# Download image from another domain. Possible ways to change the response from cloudfront.net

Tags: javascript, html, image, cloud, httpresponse

what are the possible solutions for downloading image from another domain.
In my case I have a image URL from the server side and on clicking the URL it loads the image from **cloudfront.net**

**What I need is**

download the image to local machine

**output is**

opening image in the browser

**code**

`<a id="download" href="api_url_of_image.jpg" download>download</a>`

Since its coming from the **cloudfront.net** and I don't have access to the API the **Content-Disposition** is a limited option

is there a way to add this in the **cloudfront.net** server

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What exactly do you mean "from the server side"? Like, are you getting it with your own server or is the external server returning the url to you? And what do you mean with "download to the local machine"? Like clicking should initiate a download instead of showing in browser or should it download automatically without user interaction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @icecub its from an external server and while clicking on the download the image should  initiate download

Comment: @RobertPro Not the right way, I have used the canvas to create the image and then downloaded